# Just use only one property from the Struct

Tags: swift

I am trying to build an `AddPeople` object to post to end point. Someone `accepts` or `rejects` the request. The following implementation works for `Accept` workflow.

Now, I wonder how to integrate the `Reject` workflow in the following implementation in simplified version. `info` object can have only `let userInfo = Information(Accept:"Please accept him")` or `let userInfo = Information(Reject:"Please accept him")`

My current implementation is as follows:

```
struct AddPeople: Codable {
    let id: String
    let info: Information
}

struct Information: Codable {
    let Accept: String
    //let Reject: String ?????
}

if isAcceptBtnClicked{
    let userInfo = Information(Accept:"Please accept him")
}else
{
  // let userInfo = Information(Reject:"Please reject him") ????
}

let addPeople = AddPeople(id : userId, info: userInfo)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using optionals:

```
struct Information: Codable {
    let accept: String?
    let reject: String?

    init(accept: String? = nil, reject: String? = nil) {
        self.accept = accept
        self.reject = reject
    }
}
```

Then you can call your `Information` in either way:

```
let userInfoAccept = Information(accept: "Please accept him")
let userInfoReject = Information(reject: "Please reject him")
```

Note that when you encode an `Information` to JSON, `nil` properties will be skipped:

```
let data = try! JSONEncoder().encode(userInfoReject)
let jsonStr = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
print(jsonStr) // prints {"reject":"Please reject him"}
```

Comment: do you propose the following `let userInfo = Information(Accept:"Please accept him", Reject : nil) `???

Comment: @casillas I misunderstood your question. See the updated answer.

Comment: But the current approach, still sends `Reject` as parameter, but it is `nil`. I only want to send one of them only either Accept or Reject. Because I am forming an json data to post. Endpoint only checks either `Accept` or `Reject`.

Comment: @casillas I don't see this problem. I added my code for encoding - it encodes only non-nil properties.